# How to pause/stop recyclerview animation after notifyItemRemoved()?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have applied animation for my `recyclerview` as follows

```
  SlideInRightAnimator animator = new SlideInRightAnimator();//using custom Animation to remove the recyclerview Item
animator.setRemoveDuration(200);//specify the duration to run the animation
 mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);
```

I have applied this animation on recyclerview since I do not know the 
However I would like to cancel stop animation in my Adapter once once I do `notifyItemRemoved()`.

I understand the `onBindViewHolder` is called immediately after but not sure how can I pass my animator into my `Recyclerview` adapter or call the stop animation in general.

I have eventbus handler in the Fragment and I am calling the removeItem method on Adapter as below.

```
   public void onEventMainThread(MyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
          ......
            case DELETE:

                mAdapter.removeItem(event.getItem());
                break;
            default: break;
        }
}
```

Update: I also tried to do following after I call notify Item removed:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

But this eventually cancels the animation all together

Appreciate your kind response

Comment: New `notify` methods will always call the animator.

Comment: The animator has an `endAnimations()` function, you could give that a shot.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski can you elaborate little further? I only have the reference of my animator in my Fragment and not in the Adapter.

Comment: @AlexTownsend tried, unfortunately didn't work :(

Comment: Alternatively I shall appreciate if there is a way to apply animation to a specific view holder specifically during the remove item method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with an option that works. I am sure there are better options, but here's what I did. 
  In my Adapter class, I copied the reference of the view holder within `onBindViewHolder` method. And then in the`onRemoveItem` method I used the viewHolder's `itemview` to animate using `ObjectAnimator` and Animation set. After the animation , I made the viewholder copy to be null.
  This way I was able to achieve animation on individual view.